# Bootstrap asp.net display mobile view with Multiview

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my code using bootstrap, the image will change accordingly to sizes.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row" >
<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">  
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/loginimage.jpg" />    <!--Mobile-->
</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/loginimage.jpg" />   <!--Tab-->
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-12 hidden-lg">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/loginimage.jpg" />   <!--Desktop-->
</div>

<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-12" id="img">     
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/loginimage.jpg" />  <!--Large-->          
 </div>
```

Can someone teach me how I can add `Multiview` such that for `Large` and `Desktop`, the `Multiview` can be in the center of the image, and when it becomes `Tab` or `Mobile`, the `Multiview` will be right below the image?

I know I can add a `Multiview` in each size, but I just want to add one `Multiview` so that I can do just one code on that `Multiview` and not each and every `Multiview`.

Desktop/Large View:

[image]

Mobile/Tab View:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any pictorial representation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes I include pictures for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
<style type="text/css">
 /*You may or may not need to set width and height in this css class it will depend upon your image sizes*/
 .lg-multiview {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 35%;
  left: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
 }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <!--Mobile--><!--Tab-->
  <div class="col-sm-12  hidden-md hidden-lg">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="~/images/img.jpg" />
   <img class="img-responsive" src="~/images/multiview.jpg" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--Desktop--><!--Large-->
 <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-12">
  <img class="img-responsive lg-multiview" src="~/images/multiview.jpg" />
  <img class="img-responsive" src="~/images/img.jpg" />
 </div>
</div>
```